# Convert Hierarchical Dictionary to List<KeyValuePair<Document,File>>()

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary which is like `Dictionary<Document, File[ n ]>`
i want to convert that Dictionary to `List<KeyValuePair<Document, File>>`
which is flat system

currently i'm using foreach to convert that list is it possible with Linq?

```
     var documentFileList = RepositoryFactory.FileRepository.GetFiles(_case);

  var retVal = new List<KeyValuePair<Document, File>>();
  if (documentFileList != null)
  {
    foreach (var docFileKeyPair in documentFileList)
    {
      if (docFileKeyPair.Value != null)
      {
        foreach (var fileEntity in docFileKeyPair.Value)
        {
          var document = docFileKeyPair.Key as Document;
          if (document != null)
          {
            retVal.Add(new KeyValuePair<Document, File>(document, fileEntity));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `foreach` -> `Select`. `foreach foreach` -> `SelectMany`

Comment: Why do you want to use Linq? Is there something wrong with your code? For large/huge data storage simple simple for loop is much much faster then Linq solution.

Comment: @MaciejLos  No Code is working perfectly just wanted to convert it in Linq to reduce the line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `Linq`, you could do this.

```
var flattenList = documentFileList.SelectMany(x=>x.Value.Where(v=> v != null).Select(s=> new KeyValuePair<Document, File>(x.Key, s)))
                                  .ToList();
```

Check this [`example code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zi7vrB)

Comment: How about including `null` checks from the OP code.

Comment: Thanks @HariPrasad